# Prevent data refresh in React-Query by data hash matching

Tags: reactjs, react-query

The API that I hit with React-Query returns a set of data and a hash key for this data in a form like so:

```
{
orders:[{order1},{order2},....]
dataHash:number
}
```

I Use this dataHash to check if the request results are equal inside `useQuery()` options to make it easy for reach-query to compare big datasets on it's own like so:

```
isDataEqual:(oldData, newData)=>oldData?.dataHash === newData.dataHash, //do not refresh page if hashes are equal
```

The API also has a feature that allows not to send a dataset if the dataHash matches with the one in a request. In such case it only returns the following:

```
{
orders:[] //empty array here
dataHash:number
}
```

But since my compare function only looks at dataHash the new data will not be used and everything will work as expected.

The problem I have currently is that I cannot seem to find a built-in way in react-query to save the dataHash from the old request so that it is being passed as a parameter into the new one. Ideally I would like to see react-query passing the old data into the request function so I can compare it myself but this is not an option.

I also found that it passes some sort of metadata object into the request query, but I have not found a way to mutate this object for any particular request. Am I missing Something here?

```
  const getOrders = async (metadata:any): Promise<ShowOrdersResponse> => {
    console.log(metadata) //this holds the "meta" object and query keys
   
    const request: ShowOrdersRequest = {
      searchParam: mySearchParam,
      dataHash: 12//dataHash
    };

    const {data} = await secureAxios.post<ShowOrdersResponse>(ApiEndpoints.ShowOrders, request)
    return data;
  }

  const {data} = useQuery<ShowWorkOrdersResponse>(['workorders', mySearchParam], getOrders, {
    cacheTime: 30000,
    refetchInterval: 5000,
    isDataEqual:(oldData, newData)=>oldData?.dataHash === newData.dataHash, //do not refresh page if hashes are equal, this works as charm
    meta:{dataHash:555}  //I am able to pass this "meta" object into the request query, but cannot mutate it
  });
```

Edit1:
I implemented the proposed solution but it still does not solve the problem completely. Currently I am saving the returned dataHash from server inside the component state like so:

```
onSuccess: (data) => setDataHash(data?.data.dataHash)
```

Later I call useQuery() with different search params, which it considers as a totally different request, yet since I'm sending the same hash I get no results back. isDataEqual() returns false and updates the data with empty result.

I think I need an ability to save the dataHash per-request(starting with undefined) but this means that queryFn needs to have access to "oldData.data.dataHash" to send it in. and currently i do not see how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever you return from the `queryFn` will be put into the query cache, and will thus be available as `data` returned from `useQuery` as well as on the `isDataEqual` function (because that gets passed the same `data`). So I would do:

```
const getOrders = async (): Promise<ShowOrdersResponse> => {
   
    const request: ShowOrdersRequest = {
      searchParam: mySearchParam,
      dataHash: 12
    };

    const { data } = await secureAxios.post<ShowOrdersResponse>(ApiEndpoints.ShowOrders, request)
    return {
      data,
      dataHash
    }
  }

useQuery(
  ['workorders', mySearchParam],
  getOrders,
  {
    isDataEqual:(oldData, newData) => oldData?.dataHash === newData.dataHash,
  }
)
```

of course, one drawback would be that you'd need to unwrap `data.data` then in your component, but you can work around that with the `select` function:

```
useQuery(
  ['workorders', mySearchParam],
  getOrders,
  {
    isDataEqual:(oldData, newData) => oldData?.dataHash === newData.dataHash,
    select: data => data.data
  }
)
```

this works because `isDataEqual` gets passed the data from the cache directly, while each component (observer) gets passed the data after running through `select`. So basically, you would only pass the `dataHash` through so that you can use it in `isDataEqual`.

Comment: I have not been able to figure out how to properly use the "select" with the typescript implementation, so I ended up manually unwrapping the data, but aside from that solution works great. Thanks!

Comment: I can take a look at a codesandbox example if you have one. I think what works best is to explicitly type annotate the `data` that goes into the select function.

Comment: I edited the question to describe my most recent delema

Comment: I don't understand why you would need the `onSuccess` with the proposed solution. The dataHash for each query would be stored in the query cache alongside the actual data. In the queryFn, you can get the old data via `queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey)`, and the queryKey is injected via the queryFunctionContext. You can skip doing the request if the query hash is the same if that is what you want.

Comment: using queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey) was a key here. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to modify `queryFn` so that it receives
cached data as a second optional paramter and returns it whenever appropriate.
[See details in the related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75221074/3824328)