# Is there a way for react-query to revalidate cached data in case server response is OK but does not contain actual data?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm exploring react-query but couldn't find an example for one particular use case.

A demo todo API server returns the following JSON for `getTodos(ifModifiedSince=1234567)` request:

In case todo list not modified since specified time:
`{"status":"not_modified"}`

Otherwise:
`{"status":"ok","todos":[{"userId":1,"id":2,"title":"TodoItem1","completed":false}],"lastModified":"1234589"}`

The closest I came up with:

```
const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(
    [todosQueryKey],
    () => {
      const lastModified = data?.lastModified || '';
      const result = getTodos({
        ifModifiedSince: lastModified,
      });
      return result;
    },
    {
      select: (newData): GetTodosResponse | undefined => {
        let resolvedData = newData;
        if (newData.status === StatusNotModified) {

          //! This actually does not work because getQueryData
          //! already returns data from most recent 'not_modified' request.
          resolvedData = queryClient.getQueryData([todosQueryKey]) || newData;
        }

        resolvedData.todos?.sort((a: TodoItem, b: TodoItem) => b.id - a.id);
        return resolvedData;
      },
      refetchInterval: 5000,
      staleTime: Infinity,
      keepPreviousData: true,
    }
  );
```

What is the correct way to do the above mentioned task with react-query?

Comment: this seems like a weird api and more something that should be solved with http headers and status codes, because then, the browser cache will take care of giving you the right data ...

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to use `useQuery()` as usual but instead modify `getTodos()` function
so that it receives cached data as an optional second parameter and
returns it if `status==='not_modified'`:

```
export const getTodos = async (
  req: GetTodosRequest,
  currentData?: GetTodosResponse | undefined
): Promise<GetTodosResponse> => {
  return todosApi
    .get(`/todos/`, {
      params: req,
    })
    .then((resp) => {
      const newData = validateResponse(resp);
      if (newData.status === StatusNotModified) {
        // If server responded with StatusNotModified,
        // return cached data if any.
        return currentData || newData;
      }
      return newData;
    });
};

const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(
    [todosQueryKey],
    () => {
      const lastModified = data?.lastModified || '';
      const result = getTodos(
        {
          ifModifiedSince: lastModified,
        },
        data
      );
      return result;
    },
    {
      select: (newData): GetTodosResponse => {
        newData.todos?.sort((a: TodoItem, b: TodoItem) => b.id - a.id);
        return newData;
      },
      onSuccess: () => {
        setWaitingForResponse(false);
      },
      refetchInterval: 5000,
      staleTime: Infinity,
    }
  );
```